# How to specify a VS Code binding to upload a file from /tmp to blob storage in an Azure Function

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Function written in Python 3.8 that creates a text file in /tmp. I want to upload it to blob storage. I am forced to develop locally in VS Code and need a binding in function.json. The problem is that the binding wants me to specify a data item that represents the blob, and since I am creating the blob from scratch by uploading a text file to the Container in the Storage account, I do not have any such data item in my code. So I always error.

Specifically, I have a container named "swsw-2020" in my storage account. Here is the code I am using to upload the file from /tmp to that container.

```
    try:
        from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient # noqa
        # Create the BlobServiceClient that is used to call the Blob service for the storage account
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)

        # Upload the output file, use destination for the blob name
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
            container=container_name, blob=destination)
        with open(filename, "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
    except Exception as err:
        log_error(f"Failed to upload '{filename}' to Azure Blob Storage: {err}")
```

And here is my function.json snippet, which is obviously wrong but I have absolutely no idea how to make it right.

```
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "data",
      "path": "swsw-2020",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
```

I am completely open to better ways to do this. I just want to get my TXT file in /tmp uploaded to a blob in the "swsw-2020" container in my Storage account.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

You can use a simply way to dynamic set the blob name:

This is the function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "route": "{test}",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test1/{test}.txt",
      "connection": "str",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, for example, if you want to create a blob named 1.txt, you can hit the function like this: `http://localhost:7071/api/1`

**Original Answer:**

You can upload the file before stored in some folder.(This is because maybe you will face some problem about access permission.)

It seems you are not using output binding, just connect to storage manully.

The output binding should be used like this:

**`_init_.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest,outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream],) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    testdata = 'this is test.'
    outputblob.set(testdata)
    name = req.params.get('name')
    return func.HttpResponse(f"This is output binding test, "+name)
```

**`function.json`**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test1/test.txt",
      "connection": "str",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if have more doubts.

Comment: Thank you! But that hardcodes and uses the same filename every time. How do I make that a variable in the binding in function.json? I'd imagine it would be something in braces, but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: @JohnM.Linebarger Hi, I am very sorry for reply too late. You can use some simply way like using route to dynamic set the blob name.

Comment: @JohnM.Linebarger Please have a look of my updated answer.:)